# Zooming in an NSView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, appkit, nsscrollview

I have an NSView in which the user can draw circles. These circles are stored as an array of NSBezierPaths, and in drawRect:, I loop through the array and call `-stroke` on each of the paths. How do I add a button to zoom in and out the NSView? Just change the bounds of the view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Send your view [a `scaleUnitSquareToSize:` message](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/scaleUnitSquareToSize:).

Comment: Please update the link. You can use the link provided by my answer.

Answer (score 9):

You might also find this informative:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1346/_index.html

The code in that document lets you add a "scale" property to a view.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers didn't work for my scenario but led me to a solution.

The updated link to @Peter's answer was helpful: [scaleUnitSquareToSize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483721-scaleunitsquaretosize?language=objc)

I have found two soultions for zooming:

1. Cropping the bounds manually
2. Scalling the bounds with `scaleUnitSquareToSize`

I have created a small test project. Both solutions can be found on my GitHub repo : [BoundsAndFramesCroppingAndScalling](https://github.com/Darkwonder/BoundsAndFramesCroppingAndScalling/tree/master)

To understand bounds vs frames read this SO article: [difference-between-the-frame-and-the-bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210047/cocoa-whats-the-difference-between-the-frame-and-the-bounds).

Swift scalling code:

```
let scaleSize = NSSize(width: 0.5, height: 0.5)
// 0.5 - Half the size
// 1.0 - No calling
// 2.0 - double the size , ... etc
myView?.scaleUnitSquare(to: scaleSize)
myView?.needsDisplay = true
```