# ios6 autolayout constraints

Tags: ios, ios6, autolayout

I'm trying to figure out how to use constraints on a UIViewController (inside a UITabBarController which is inside a UINavigationController)...
More than a thousand words, here's what I'm trying to do...

[image: Portrait]
[image: Lanscape]

Actually, the first one is 100px height no matter the orientation, the second is an Ad (so 50px in portrait and 32px in Landscape), and finally a tableView that will take the rest.

So far here is my code:

```
PMMainProfilHeader  *profilHeader = [[PMMainProfilHeader alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:profilHeader];
    [profilHeader release];

    UIView *adTest = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
    adTest.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:adTest];
    [adTest release];

    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:_tableView];
    [_tableView release];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[profilHeader]-0-|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(profilHeader)]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[adTest]-0-|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(adTest)]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[_tableView]-0-|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_tableView)]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[profilHeader]-0-[adTest]-0-[_tableView]-0-|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(profilHeader, adTest, _tableView)]];
```

But of course it doesn't work... and I'm not able to tell why, when I resume debug a couple of time I get this block of comment from debugger :

```
2013-02-22 00:17:13.207 MyApplication[6822:907] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d0b20d0 H:[UIView:0x1d0ae7e0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1c596de0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d0b2090 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x1d0ae7e0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1c596de0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d0b2000 H:[PMMainProfilHeader:0x1d09f5b0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1c596de0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d0b2320 H:|-(0)-[PMMainProfilHeader:0x1d09f5b0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1c596de0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c5dcb10 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x1d0ae7e0.midX ==>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c5daf80 h=--& v=--& PMMainProfilHeader:0x1d09f5b0.midX == + 160>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d0b20d0 H:[UIView:0x1d0ae7e0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1c596de0 )>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2013-02-22 00:17:41.706 MyApplication[6822:907] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c5ab460 V:[PMMainProfilHeader:0x1d09f5b0]-(0)-[UIView:0x1d0ae7e0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c5ab3f0 V:|-(0)-[PMMainProfilHeader:0x1d09f5b0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1c596de0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c5dcca0 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x1d0ae7e0.midY ==>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c5db050 h=--& v=--& PMMainProfilHeader:0x1d09f5b0.midY == + 50>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c5ab460 V:[PMMainProfilHeader:0x1d09f5b0]-(0)-[UIView:0x1d0ae7e0]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2013-02-22 00:17:43.382 MyApplication[6822:907] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1d0c0530 h=--& v=--& UITableView:0x1db44600.midX ==>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c5ab160 H:[UITableView:0x1db44600]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1c596de0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c5ab120 H:|-(0)-[UITableView:0x1db44600]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1c596de0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d0b2000 H:[PMMainProfilHeader:0x1d09f5b0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1c596de0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d0b2320 H:|-(0)-[PMMainProfilHeader:0x1d09f5b0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1c596de0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c5daf80 h=--& v=--& PMMainProfilHeader:0x1d09f5b0.midX == + 160>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c5ab160 H:[UITableView:0x1db44600]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1c596de0 )>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2013-02-22 00:17:45.290 MyApplication[6822:907] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c5dcce0 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x1d0ae7e0(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c5ab510 V:[UITableView:0x1db44600]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1c596de0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c5ab4b0 V:[UIView:0x1d0ae7e0]-(0)-[UITableView:0x1db44600]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c5ed510 h=-&- v=-&- UILayoutContainerView:0x1c5d1440.height == UIWindow:0x1c564480.height>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c5ef2e0 h=--- v=--- V:[UIWindow:0x1c564480(480)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c5eb9e0 h=-&- v=-&- UINavigationTransitionView:0x1c5d2b20.height == UILayoutContainerView:0x1c5d1440.height>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c5e9f80 h=-&- v=-&- UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x1d0ba580.height == UINavigationTransitionView:0x1c5d2b20.height>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c5e8610 h=-&- v=-&- UILayoutContainerView:0x1d096c30.height == UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x1d0ba580.height>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c5e6ed0 h=-&- v=-&- UITransitionView:0x1d0999d0.height == UILayoutContainerView:0x1d096c30.height - 49>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c5e5980 h=-&- v=-&- UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x1c5cb7a0.height == UITransitionView:0x1d0999d0.height - 20>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1d0c0710 h=--& v=--& UITableView:0x1db44600.midY ==>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c5e4270 h=-&- v=-&- UIView:0x1c596de0.height == UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x1c5cb7a0.height>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c5dcca0 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x1d0ae7e0.midY ==>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c5ab4b0 V:[UIView:0x1d0ae7e0]-(0)-[UITableView:0x1db44600]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2013-02-22 00:17:48.283 MyApplication[6822:907] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c5ab510 V:[UITableView:0x1db44600]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1c596de0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c5ed510 h=-&- v=-&- UILayoutContainerView:0x1c5d1440.height == UIWindow:0x1c564480.height>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c5ef2e0 h=--- v=--- V:[UIWindow:0x1c564480(480)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c5eb9e0 h=-&- v=-&- UINavigationTransitionView:0x1c5d2b20.height == UILayoutContainerView:0x1c5d1440.height>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c5e9f80 h=-&- v=-&- UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x1d0ba580.height == UINavigationTransitionView:0x1c5d2b20.height>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c5e8610 h=-&- v=-&- UILayoutContainerView:0x1d096c30.height == UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x1d0ba580.height>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c5e6ed0 h=-&- v=-&- UITransitionView:0x1d0999d0.height == UILayoutContainerView:0x1d096c30.height - 49>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c5e5980 h=-&- v=-&- UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x1c5cb7a0.height == UITransitionView:0x1d0999d0.height - 20>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1d0c0710 h=--& v=--& UITableView:0x1db44600.midY ==>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c5e4270 h=-&- v=-&- UIView:0x1c596de0.height == UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x1c5cb7a0.height>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1d0c0750 h=--& v=--& V:[UITableView:0x1db44600(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c5ab510 V:[UITableView:0x1db44600]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1c596de0 )>
```

Thanks for reading the whole (huge) post !! Hope someone know why it doesn't work !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting weird error talking about constraints in Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664115/getting-weird-error-talking-about-constraints-in-xcode)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer...

I just had to call setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints for each view I'm using constraints with :

```
[profilHeader setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[adTest setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[_tableView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

Hope it helps someone...

Comment: I can't imagine doing this all in code was more efficient than doing it in Interface Builder. It's easier to set, you get visual feedback on what happens and when there's a conflict you either see something going wrong in the UI or there's a very clear warning or error. Also you prevent the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints by doing this.