# "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" error with UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, interface-builder

Created a simple ViewController, and added UIScrollView with a xib. When I'm trying to change the height of the scroll view, I'm getting a weird exception:

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.     Probably at least one
>   of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try
>   this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you
>   don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or
>   constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
>   
>   (Names: '|':UIView:0xa4ab830 )>
>
> Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger. The
>   methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView
>   listed in  may also be helpful.

Here's how my xib looks:
[image]

Found on the SO that setting content size and setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property to YES might help. Tried it, didn't work:

```
topScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
topScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000, 2000);
```

EDIT: added screenshot
[image]

Comment: How do you change the height of the scroll view? And when you use auto layout, you will not even need to set the content size anymore.

Comment: I change height by dragging the bottom margin of the UIScrollView in the Interface Builder.

Comment: Also changed it by changing "Height" in the "View" division in the Interface builder (in the picture, on the left).

Comment: So you have tried changing the existing bottom space margin of the scroll view to the superview from 494 to something else?

Comment: You missed out the important part of the error message. Please include all of it. The only way to get that error is to try and change the frame in code or to add subviews in code. Please include some code.

Comment: You meen the margin on this screenshot? http://i.stack.imgur.com/oVMQs.png

If so, I have changed it, but the result was the same.

Comment: You have removed the important part of the error message. Please can you include ALL of the error message that you get.

Comment: Actually, I included all the error messages... I can only add the the execution breaks at the line "[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting weird error talking about constraints in Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664115/getting-weird-error-talking-about-constraints-in-xcode)