# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Actually integrated camera application using xib, in that I placed uiview on a view, after that I put imageview, again view on imageview for cropping.  then run the project I got this error.

> 2013-07-23 12:45:49.936 Camera_App1[30668:907] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)

```
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1f5b3d10 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x1f5a2f70(460)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1f5a3c80 V:[UIView:0x1f5a31b0]-(385)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1f5a3120 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1f5a3f80 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x1f5a3120]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1f5a2f70 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1f5a3f40 V:[UIView:0x1f5a3120]-(63)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1f5a2f70 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1f5a3bc0 V:|-(61)-[UIView:0x1f5a31b0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1f5a3120 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1f5a3c80 V:[UIView:0x1f5a31b0]-(385)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1f5a3120 )>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2013-07-23 12:45:58.697 Camera_App1[30668:907] media type=public.image
2013-07-23 12:45:58.701 Camera_App1[30668:907] global=public.image
2013-07-23 12:45:58.858 Camera_App1[30668:907] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1f5a3c80 V:[UIView:0x1f5a31b0]-(385)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1f5a3120 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1f5a3f80 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x1f5a3120]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1f5a2f70 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1f5a3f40 V:[UIView:0x1f5a3120]-(63)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1f5a2f70 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1f5a3bc0 V:|-(61)-[UIView:0x1f5a31b0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1f5a3120 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1f53a430 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x1f5a2f70(460)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1f5a3c80 V:[UIView:0x1f5a31b0]-(385)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1f5a3120 )>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting weird error talking about constraints in Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664115/getting-weird-error-talking-about-constraints-in-xcode)

Comment: The best answer about constraints issues is here: [Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints, will attempt to recover by breaking constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11664115/2725435)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The error is what it says, and gives quite clear instructions for you to begin debugging. There are two constraints that conflict. Each instructs the Auto Layout runtime to do something that contradicts the other.

If you are creating and adding views programmatically, then chances are Auto Resizing attributes have been automatically translated to Auto Layout constraints.

So, the first thing to try is, with your programmatically created views, disable this by setting:

```
myProgrammaticView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

Comment: If I want to use one particular view without any constraints, how I can avoid warnings...

Comment: if the view has no constraints then there will be no warnings

Comment: I want constraints alongwith i want to use autoresizing mask without warnings.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, after hours of searching, it turned out the problem was because in-call or hotspot status bar was toggled, (hotspot is on, in a phone call), to fix the problem, in appdelegate I added:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, willChangeStatusBarFrame newStatusBarFrame: CGRect) {
    let windows = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows

    for window in windows {
        window.removeConstraints(window.constraints)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solves my problem too. However, when I try another case, leave In-Call Status bar on (wider green bar), and then start the app, try to toggle it, I see the error again. Do you see the same?

Answer (score 3):

Try this steps, it helps me.

> **Select your object > Editor > Resolve Auto Layout Issues > Reset to Suggested Constraints**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is very old but this is my experience and Solution.

Select view (UILabel, UIImage etc) Editor > Pin > (Select...) to Superview Editor > Resolve Auto Layout Issues > Add Missing Constraints

This error is to conflict between constraints that you have added. Remove the constraints that are not required. Not to use more than one constraint in the same direction and type.

[image]

I would recommend that you use SnapKit. It is an Autolayout framework, very convenient to use

```
 import SnapKit

 var label = UILabel()

 label.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
    make.centerX.equalTo(0)
    make.centerY.equalTo(0)
    make.width.equalTo(30)
    make.height.equalTo(30)
 }
```

https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit Hope this is helpful:)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting this error due to a Navigation Bar. Adding New UIViewController was causing this error.

> I removed the old navigation bar and then re-added it by going to
>   *Editor* ➞ *Embed In* ➞ *Navigation Controller*.

Answer (score -2):

I reset to suggested Constraints and it resolved the issue, [see here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0YDF.jpg)

Select your object > Editor > Resolve Auto Layout Issues > Reset to Suggested Constraints