# NSLayoutConstraint UIInputSetContainerView Status Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

platform: iOS  XCode
langugae:Objective-C 
When the status bars height is 40px,we run the code ,the error happened like the following

```
     Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
[
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe903dd5940 UIInputSetContainerView:0x7fe903dd2e50.top == UITextEffectsWindow:0x7fe903e554b0.top + 20>,
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe903d82c00 UIInputSetContainerView:0x7fe903dd2e50.top == UITextEffectsWindow:0x7fe903e554b0.top>
]

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 

    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe903dd5940  UInputSetContainerView:0x7fe903dd2e50.top == UITextEffectsWindow:0x7fe903e554b0.top>
```

So what should I do?Window of AppDelegate changed position.

[normal situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjPSt.png)

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmMHH.png)

Comment: Check your constraint , It may be any constraint conflict in your UI. and check also this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803801/unable-to-simultaneously-satisfy-constraints, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327145/unable-to-simultaneously-satisfy-constraints-no-constraints-in-place

Comment: thank you and I have seen the question in the URL but its not same with my error,thank you again

Comment: Have you solved the error?

Comment: no ,I have try many ways to solve the problem,but they all no use..

Comment: Ok.. No issue It does happen.