# How to let lldb print the description written in an Objective-C category

Tags: objective-c, xcode, autolayout, categories, lldb

An incredible tip for debugging constraint issues [print the constraint`s id in lldb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31833436/4864400)

But what should I do to let the lldb print my category`s description?

```
@interface NSLayoutConstraint (Description)

@end

@implementation NSLayoutConstraint (Description)

-(NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"id: %@, constant: %f", self.identifier, self.constant];
}

@end
```

Help is really appreciated :)

Comment: You should never override a method in a category. It's undefined behavior.

Comment: @rmaddy but the link  says it work...

Comment: It may work. It may not. That's the problem with undefined behavior.

Comment: I test again, It just works..... :))

Answer (score 1):

You can use the description method in two ways.  One, if in the code in your app somewhere you do:

```
NSLog(@"My Object: %@", my_object);
```

then `%@` specifier will print the NSString returned by the "description" method of your object.

Another way is in the debugger:

lldb (and gdb before it) has a command called `po` - which is short for `print-object`.  It's job is to take some expression, evaluate it, interpret the result (in the case of ObjC) as an NSObject and send that object the `description` method.

So in the debugger you can just call

```
(lldb) po object
```

and get your printout.

One detail, though:  `po` actually first checks if the object responds to `debugDescription` and it will call that in preference to `description`.  So if you are extending an object that implements `debugDescription` (some Kit objects do this) then `po` will show you the result of the debugDescription method, not your description.