# How to find unsatisfiable constraints in swift

Tags: swift, autolayout, xcode7, nslayoutconstraint

Firstly, I set height constraints id named "$test$" in Attributes Inspector. 
(Actually, I don't know which view should I select and set ID. I made it as a test.)
Then I put the following code.

```
extension NSLayoutConstraint {

override public var description: String {
    let id = identifier ?? ""
    return "id: \(id), constantTestResult: \(constant)"

}
```

}

The result is

```
"id: , constantTestResult: 32.0",
"id: , constantTestResult: 200.0",
"id: , constantTestResult: 15.0",
"id: , constantTestResult: 15.0",
"id: , constantTestResult: 4.0",
"id: $test$, constantTestResult: 129.0"
```

id does not show number.  I found the post here:  [AutoLayout, Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630315/autolayout-unable-to-simultaneously-satisfy-constraints)

 I did it like that but not successful. Please help me.

Comment: you mean when you use `$test$` it works but if you use `43` it doesn't ??

Comment: What do u mean 43? Actually, I'm not clear to give the constraints. Do I need to give name to each constraints in each view? If so, I don't want to give name all.