# Is there a way to add an identifier to Auto Layout Constraints in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

After doing some visual layout in Interface Builder I've created some constraints that I want to access at runtime. Is there a way to label or identify constraints in Interface Builder so they can be looked-up later?

The reason I want to do this is I need to perform some calculation base upon the constraints that are visually specified. I am aware that Apple has provided the [Visual Format Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH3-SW1) and I could specify the constraints programmatically in a controller. I rather not use this approach so I don't lose the design time feedback of IB.

#### Edit

Making a referencing outlet did work, but the question still stands.

Comment: Can you expand on "I also tried to make a referencing outlet to the constraint but that didn't work either."? Making an outlet is probably what you should be doing.

Comment: Yes, I went back and tried it again and the IBOutlet did work. I'm still wondering if there is another way to label the constraint with an identifier and look it up later.

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if Xcode generated unique identifiers for each constraint? Now where was I? O yeah, `id66`, `id67`, ... groan

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Update:**

As explained by Bartłomiej Semańczyk in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31831576/1630618), there is now an **Identifier** field visible in the *Attributes Inspector* for the `NSLayoutConstraint` making it unnecessary to expose this field yourself.  Just select the constraint in the *Document Outline* view or in the Storyboard view and then add an identifier in the *Attributes Inspector* on the right.

---

**Earlier Answer:**

Yes, this can be done.  `NSLayoutConstraint` has a property called `identifier` than can be exposed in *Interface Builder* and assigned.  To demo this, I created a *Single View Application* that has a single subview that is a red box.  This subview has 4 constraints: width, height, centered horizontally in container, centered vertically in container.  I gave the width constraint the identifier `redBoxWidth` by doing the following:

1. Click on the width constraint in the *Document Layout View*.  Then in the *Identity Inspector* under **User Defined Runtime Attributes**, click on the `+` under **Key Path**.  Change *keyPath* to *identifier*, change the **Type** *Boolean* to *String*, and set the **Value** to `redBoxWidth`.

   [image: naming a constraint]
2. Then in `ViewDidLoad` it is possible to find the constraint by name and change its value:

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController {

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           for subview in view.subviews as [UIView] {
               for constraint in subview.constraints() as [NSLayoutConstraint] {
                   if constraint.identifier == "redBoxWidth" {
                       constraint.constant = 300
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: This is a really good answer. I had hoped there would be a more direct way of naming the constraint in IB, but this will work. Thanks for the excellent answer. I was already aware of most of these pieces except the `identifier` attribute and you put it all together nicely.

Answer (score 16):

1. Since Xcode 7 you can do it in storyboard:

[image]

2. However if you set up your constraint in code, do the following:

   ```
   let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint() 
   constraint.identifier = "identifier"
   ```
3. For these constraints you have set up in storyboard, but you must set identifier in code:

   ```
   for subview in view.subviews {
       for constraint in subview.constraints() {
           constraint.identifier = "identifier"
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Is there a way to set an ID in the visual layout language too?

Answer (score 9):

Also you could link constraint to properties of your controller as you do for any other components. Just ctrl drag it into your code:

[image]

And then it will be accessible in code of your controller as property:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *myConstraint;
```

And you could change it value for example:

```
self.myConstraint.constant=100.;
```

Answer (score 6):

Just adding on to @vacawama's answer. You can write a `UIView` category and pull out constraints using a simple function, as opposed to copy/pasting loops everywhere you need to find a constraint:

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (EasyAutolayout)

-(NSLayoutConstraint *)constraintForIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;

@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "UIView+EasyAutolayout.h"

@implementation UIView (EasyAutolayout)

-(NSLayoutConstraint *)constraintForIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier {

    for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in self.constraints) {
        if ([constraint.identifier isEqualToString:identifier]) {
            return constraint;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 5):

Take the IBOutlet of your auto layout constraint.

There is one property called **constant** in the **NSLayoutConstraint** class.

For eg, you've taken the IBOutlet of height constraint of any of the views from your IB, and you want to change it's height programmatically, all you need to do is:

```
 constraint.constant = isMoreHeight ? height1 : height2;
```

After doing this, you need to update all other views in the view hierarchy of the superview. To do this you'll need to write below line:

```
[self setLayoutIfNeeded];
```

For better user experience, you can put this line inside your animations block for smoother transition effects,

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
      [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: My question was how to identify the constraint in IB not how to update it, but thank you for the answer anyway as it does fit within the greater context of the question.

Answer (score 4):

What about this:

```
if let myconstraint = self.view.constraints.filter( { $0.identifier == "myconstraintId" }).first {
    // TODO: your code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my two cents for OSX (previous answers deal with UIKit..)

it work for OSX, too:

```
final private func getConstraintForButton(){
    let constraints  = self.myButton.constraints
    for constraint in constraints  {
        if constraint.identifier == "redBoxWidth" {
            constraint.constant = 300
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Note: seems NOT working on custom NSView, instead...