# Correct way to delete a NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

In my apps I'm working a lot with constraints, in most cases with animations as well. In certain circumstances I need to remove constraints and add new ones.

As I need to support iOS 7 as well, I'm not able to use the `active` property, which would else be the solution for me.

The way to remove constraints is to use the `removeConstraint` method on a `UIView`.

Is it possible to create a method like

```
constraint.remove()
```

so you don't have to know which view is taking care over the constraint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've ended up using the method `autoRemove` provided by the `PureLayout` library: https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout

This method finds the commonSuperview using the firstItem or secondItem and removes the constraint from the correct view.

It resulted in this one liner:

```
containerTopConstraint.autoRemove()
```

Answer (score 17):

What I do is create arrays of the constraints that I wish to be able to add/remove and simply use the following:

```
@property NSMutableArray *newConstraints;
```

Fill up the `newConstraints`

iOS7 and iOS8:

```
[self.viewToChange addConstraints:self.newConstraints];
[self.viewToChange removeConstraints:self.newConstraints];
```

or iOS8 only, use the new mechanism

```
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:self.newConstraints];
[NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:self.newConstraints];
```

With this you can apply a set, remove the set and apply a new set.

You can also create the initial list from the storyboard set if you can identify which constraints are which.

Comment: That's not my problem. The `viewToChange` is the problem, as I don't always know which view is caring the constraints. That's why I simply want to say `constraint.remove()`

Comment: Apologies, misunderstood. A solution would be to map all the constraints that matter in a dictionary using their `identifier` as the key and view as the value. You can then find the current view by looking up by identifer. For hand coded constraints you can set the identifer in code. You can also set it from IB: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791597/is-there-a-way-to-add-an-identifier-to-auto-layout-constraints-in-interface-buil

Comment: I could use that identifier to find the constraint, but how do I find the correct view using that identifier?

Comment: You would need to record it for coded constraints and do some sort of quick depth first view scan for constraints with identfiers. So recurse through each sub view and look at the constraints in the `constraints` property. Map all with an `identifer` in the dictionary with `identifier` as key and the containing view as the value. Most will be nil unless you set them. Should be pretty fast and easy do do in `viewWill/DidAppear`. You can then remove by identifer with a simple lookup of the view followed by a remove.

Comment: But that basically brings me to the same solution @dasdom provided, where you roughly iterate through each subviews constraints to check if it constains the stored NSLayoutConstraint. I'm looking for a way to just say to my constraint: remove() and let it find his parent view and remove itself

Comment: Once you have the map, you can do the equivalent of your remove. `[self.constraintMap[constraint.identifier] removeConstraint:constraint]; [self.constraintMap removeObjectWithKey: constraint.identifier]`. You can wrap all this up in a small function called `removeConstraint`. Needs some error checking for when the constraint has no identifier etc.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about activateconstraints

Answer (score 0):

No, not that I'm aware of. The automatic managing of the host view only came in iOS8.

An ugly implementation could loop over all constraints of all views to finde the view where it is on.

But normally it shouldn't be to hard to manage the constrains in a way that you always know on which view they are defined.

Comment: Well, that's true. I do know it's one out of two views. But I don't want to write these if statements each time. It would be nicer to have a clean solution for this.