# Xcode 6 unable to move UIButton with Autolayout on

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uibutton

I have some code to move my button using its tag.

```
- (void) moveButtonWithTag:(int)tag :(int)x :(int)y{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:tag];
    CGRect btFrame = button.frame;
    btFrame.origin.x = x;
    btFrame.origin.y = y;
    button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    button.frame = btFrame;
}
```

This does nothing, I have tried to move my button using the same code but instead of tags I dragged the button to the .h file, this also didn't work. Can someone help me?
I am using Xcode 6.4 iOS 8.4 Autolayout ON Sizeclasses ON. There are no constraints on any of the buttons on storyboard or created otherwise with code. The device I am testing on is iOS Simulator iPhone 6 (4.7 Inch).

Comment: Is `button` nil? Prove that it isn't. That is step one...

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using autolayout, the best practice is change `NSLayoutConstraint` that you've created (IB). https://stackoverflow.com/a/27792550/846780
2. Where you are calling `moveButtonWithTag:x:y`? Maybe you are calling it before all constraning be "applied". If you want this "dirty" approach, try to change frames on `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.
3. Check if button is nil