# Change the UIView height which is inside the UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I am trying to change the  UIView height which is inside of the tableView. UIView height should not exceed the cell height.

i was trying to set the bounds of the `view` but it did not effect the view.

how can i fix this and change height of `view`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


    UIView *view=(UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:999];

    view.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    [view setBounds:CGRectMake(view.bounds.origin.x, view.bounds.origin.y, view.bounds.size.width, 400)];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: but background colour was changed as i expected

Comment: You have to increase table cell height relating to your view. And if you are using autolayout then use the layout constraints.

Comment: can you explain how to access layout constraints inside cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: you have to create NSLayoutConstraint of view inside cell. or you can just increase hight of the cell. and give bottom constraint to the view.

Comment: if you are changing the height of control which is in cell, then at the same time you need to change cell's height also.

Comment: use this method to chnage the cell height and returns your view height as a height.
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}

Comment: Ashish Kakkad and  Kevin Mac combination of your ideas has worked.. thank you both of you....

Answer (score 0):

i found another way to do it. add a identifier to the view height constraints. and i can access it in controller like this.. link -> [Is there a way to add an identifier to Auto Layout Constraints in Interface Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791597/is-there-a-way-to-add-an-identifier-to-auto-layout-constraints-in-interface-buil)