# How to know meaning of constraints error in autolayout ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout

I have added constraints to my view in app.I am getting below error message.I am not able to undertstand what actually went wrong with constraints.So how can i understand thier exact meaning.

```
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd0135d4c30 UIImageView:0x7fd0135d7470.width == 0.634361*UIImageView:0x7fd0135d7470.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd01347c6c0 H:[UIImageView:0x7fd01347d270(20)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd01347df10 H:|-(79)-[UIImageView:0x7fd01347d270]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fd013479d10 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd01347df60 H:[UIImageView:0x7fd01347d270]-(60)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fd013479d10 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd01347eb50 UIView:0x7fd013474330.width == 1.33058*UIView:0x7fd013474330.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd01347f410 UIView:0x7fd013479d10.leading == UIView:0x7fd013479810.leading>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd01347f460 UIView:0x7fd013479d10.trailing == UIView:0x7fd013479810.trailing>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd01347f500 UIView:0x7fd013479810.width == 1.31405*UIView:0x7fd013474330.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd013481970 UIImageView:0x7fd0135d7470.width == 0.507042*UIView:0x7fd01347fcd0.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd0134819c0 UIView:0x7fd013474330.width == 0.354626*UIImageView:0x7fd0135d7470.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd0134884d0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x7fd01347fcd0(667)]>"
```

Comment: check out this link .. .http://staxmanade.com/2015/06/debugging-ios-autolayout-issues/

Comment: good but i am not able able to understand what is the issue which constraint is went wrong

Comment: you have asked the layout for something impossible. what did it say it was going to ignore to make it possible? you need to look at all associated constraints and make it always possible...

Comment: Show us error message. What you posted is just all of your constraints.

Comment: unbale to satisfy multiple constarints is the issue

Comment: You could understand the issue from the log above once you get used to VFL's.

Comment: Show screen shot of your viewcontroller in storyboard. Some conflicting constraints can cause this issue at runtime

Answer (score 0):

I founded solution by adding a unique id to each constraint.I added id from attribute inspector.After log printed the exact constraint id which i added & which was causing the issue.

Below link helped me alot
[Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints, will attempt to recover by breaking constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664115/unable-to-simultaneously-satisfy-constraints-will-attempt-to-recover-by-breakin)