# NSLayoutConstrain - Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint - Programmatically Creating Constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, visual-format-language

It runs fine and nothing is wrong except that I receive this error.

[image: Screenshot]

Below is my code.

```
NSDictionary *views = @{@"container":self.containerView,
                        @"head":self.headImageView,
                        @"userName":self.userNameLabel,
                        @"userTitle":self.userTitleLabel,
                        @"line":self.infoSeparatorLine,
                        @"articleTitle":self.articleTitleLabel
                        };

float headWidthAndHeight = 50;
NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"headWH":@(headWidthAndHeight),
                        @"userLabelWH":@(headWidthAndHeight/2),
                        };

[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[container]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[container]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];


[self.containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-15-[head(headWH)]-5-[userName]-15-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[self.containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-15-[head(headWH)]-5-[userTitle]-15-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[self.containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[line]|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[self.containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-15-[articleTitle]-15-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];


[self.containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[head(headWH)]-0-[line(1)]-8-[articleTitle]|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[self.containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[userName(userLabelWH)]-0-[userTitle(userLabelWH)]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
```

Below is the error message I receive in the debug area.

[image: Screenshot]

How do I fix it?

Comment: It's very unlikely that this question gets answered considering there are several similar questions already answered (like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30096600/2305521)) and this one only applies to your specific issue. I'd recommend you try the answer I mentioned and once you get it working feel free to answer your own question.

Comment: @fpg1503 thanks!! you save my day, change priority and warning lifted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self.containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[head(headWH)]-0-[line(1)]-8@999-[articleTitle]|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
```

Change priority below 1000 for broken constraint.