# autolayout error when landscape my screen

Tags: ios, autolayout, landscape

My app has only one view controller which needs landscape orientation and others will be in portrait. When I tried to make it landscape with code, I receive logs like this:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fece31416f0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fece0dc94b0(64)]>,
<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fece0ddf0c0 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fece0dc94b0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fece0dca270 )>,
<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fece3145cb0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fece3108140(0)]>,
<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fece31201c0 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fece3108140.bottom == UIView:0x7fece0dca270.bottom>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fece0de5700 V:[UIView:0x7fece3124110(280)]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fece0dcf870 V:[UIButton:0x7fece3137790'开始训练'(42)]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fece0dc4df0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fece0dc94b0]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fece3124110]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fece0d42c60 V:[UIView:0x7fece3124110]-(0)-[UITableView:0x7fece112a000]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fece0dec530 V:[UITableView:0x7fece112a000]-(0)-[UIButton:0x7fece3137790'开始训练']>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fece0df24c0 V:[UIButton:0x7fece3137790'开始训练']-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fece3108140]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fece3252110 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x7fece0dca270(320)]>,
 )
 Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fece0de5700 V:[UIView:0x7fece3124110(280)]>
 Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
 The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

My constrains are very simple, no error appears without changing to landscape. Anybody ever met problems like this?

Comment: read [https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/DebuggingTricksandTips.html](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/DebuggingTricksandTips.html)

Comment: also check and try answers here:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664115/unable-to-simultaneously-satisfy-constraints-will-attempt-to-recover-by-breakin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664115/unable-to-simultaneously-satisfy-constraints-will-attempt-to-recover-by-breakin)

Comment: Thank you for your attention.I solved this problem by remove all subviews of this view controller's content view when I prepare to jump to the next view controller.