# How to remove default constraints set by UIButton?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, autolayout

I'm currently trying to use Auto-Layout constraints to vertically position a UIButton's TitleLabel below its ImageView. However, I can't seem to figure out how to remove the default constraints from the UIButton. Because of this, the final set of constraints is ambiguous. How can I remove the default constraints and make my constraints work? Also, I keep seeing people using insets to accomplish this layout. Why is this? Below is my code:

```
 public class DrawerButton : UIButton
{
    public override UIButtonType ButtonType { get; } = UIButtonType.Custom;

    public override void UpdateConstraints()
    {
        this.AddConstraints(
        ImageView.WithSameCenterX(this),

        TitleLabel.Below(ImageView).Plus(10),
        TitleLabel.WithSameCenterX(this)

        );

        base.UpdateConstraints();
    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        this.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        this.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();
        base.LayoutSubviews();
    }
}
```

Generated error:

```
2016-09-28 22:31:08.163 XXXXXXXXXXX[80361:7012489] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79292ca0 V:[UIImageView:0x78efb2c0]-(10)-[UIButtonLabel:0x78e00dc0'TEST']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x792bb250 UIImageView:0x78efb2c0.centerY == XXXXXXXXX_iOS_Widgets_DrawerButton:0x793ddec0'TEST'.centerY>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x792c9310 UIButtonLabel:0x78e00dc0'TEST'.centerY == XXXXXXXXX_iOS_Widgets_DrawerButton:0x793ddec0'TEST'.centerY>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79292ca0 V:[UIImageView:0x78efb2c0]-(10)-[UIButtonLabel:0x78e00dc0'TEST']>
```

Comment: Check this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664115/unable-to-simultaneously-satisfy-constraints-will-attempt-to-recover-by-breakin) first, if you are willing to.

Comment: I saw that, thanks. I know that there are conflicting constraints. The problem is that I do not know how to remove the default constraints.

Comment: Consider changing the title of the question, as you know how to do that, but you're missing solution for an elementary issue. E.g. 'How to remove default constraints'.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension (Swift3) that will vertically position the titleLabel of a UIButton underneath the imageView.

```
extension UIButton {
    func centerButtonAndImageVertically(verticalSpacing: CGFloat = 0) {

        self.contentVerticalAlignment = .center
        self.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center

        let imageWidth = self.imageView?.frame.size.width ?? 0
        let imageHeight = self.imageView?.frame.size.height ?? 0
        let titleHeight = self.titleLabel?.frame.size.height ?? 0
        let titleWidth = self.titleLabel?.frame.size.width ?? 0

        self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: titleWidth, bottom: titleHeight+verticalSpacing*0.5, right: 0)
        self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: imageHeight+verticalSpacing*0.5, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: imageWidth)
    }
}
```

As an example, I am using the extension in the following ViewController code to get the result as in the image:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var smallButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var bigButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageOnlyButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleOnlyButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        smallButton.centerButtonAndImageVertically()
        button.centerButtonAndImageVertically()
        bigButton.centerButtonAndImageVertically(verticalSpacing: 10)
        imageOnlyButton.centerButtonAndImageVertically()
        titleOnlyButton.centerButtonAndImageVertically()
    }

}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue, didnt find the answer but for me solution that worked, was to override this UIButton's methods in my subclass:

```
override func imageRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {

    var imageFrame: CGRect = super.imageRect(forContentRect: contentRect)

    imageFrame.origin = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX - imageFrame.width / 2, y: bounds.midY - imageFrame.height)

    return imageFrame
}

override func titleRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {

    var titleFrame: CGRect = super.titleRect(forContentRect: contentRect)

    titleFrame.origin = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX - titleFrame.width / 2, y: bounds.midY)

    return titleFrame
}
```

Maybe it will help someone