# UIView shadow AND rounded corners

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer, shadow

I have a UIView which I want to have a shadow and round corners.
The problem is - a shadow requires `masksToBounds = NO` while round corners requires `masksToBounds = YES`.

The solution I found is to have a container which will have shadow and add my UIView as a subview of the container - and give it rounded corners.

This works. I have both shadow AND round corners - but it's no good.
The shadow is of a rectangle view and my image has rounded corners.

[image: Shadow and rounded corners]

How can I implement a shadow for the rounded corners?

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509547/uiview-with-rounded-corners

Comment: I don't have a problem applying rounded corners. The problem is that rounded corners along with shadow doesn't look good...

Comment: Use images masking the corners. It's far simpler, faster to code and usually better looking than any programming solution.

Comment: My problem is that the cell can change it's size from time to time using animation. Using images will make my life even harder.

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class customButton: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius:CGFloat = 0{
        didSet{
            self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth:CGFloat = 0{
        didSet{
            self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor:UIColor = UIColor.white{
        didSet{
            self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        }
    }


}
```

Set this as class for the UIView and put `maskToBound = true`. Then in the inspector set the value accordingly to get a **rounded** shadow.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the container, its clipping your view shadow. Import `QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h` . And try this code to your view

```
#import < QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

...

view.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
[view.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
[view.layer setShadowOpacity:0.7];
[view.layer setShadowRadius:5.0];
[view.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0)];
```

to know more about maskToBound see this link

[What UIView layer.masksToBounds is doing if set to YES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648681/what-uiview-layer-maskstobounds-is-doing-if-set-to-yes)

Comment: The container is the one with the shadow - it can't clip the shadow

Comment: @godmoney So why you using a container, if you can set both (shadow, corner) to your main view layer?

Comment: No - because shadow requires maskToBounds = NO and rounded corners required maskToBounds = YES.

Answer (score -2):

```
// border radius
[yourView.layer setCornerRadius:30.0f];

// border
[yourView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[yourView.layer setBorderWidth:1.5f];
 yourView.layer.masksToBounds=YES;

// drop shadow
[yourView.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
[yourView.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8];
[yourView.layer setShadowRadius:3.0];
[yourView.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0)];
```

This may help you.

Comment: What should be the value of "masksToBounds"? YES or NO?

Comment: Is the border required?

Comment: I used the code. The rounded corners are visible but the shadow is not (masksToBounds=YES).

Comment: change the shadow Colour and border Colour.

Comment: .maskToBounds limits the drawing of the shadow. This answer is incorrect.