# Wrong view size on 3.5 screen

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator

When running my iOS app on a 3.5 inch iPhone Simulator, self.view.frame.size.height is reporting 548px. What is the right way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you see this behavior in `viewDidLoad`, right?
The screen dimensions are not final while in `viewDidLoad`. You should only rely on the view's frame in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method.

Answer (score 0):

it's because you're calling this from `viewDidLoad` right?

I bet calling the NSLog in this function instead comes back with the correct height;

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"%f", self.view.frame.size.height);
}
```

You should really be using `self.view.bounds` instead of `self.view.frame`

for more information about why and how view this SO: 
["Incorrect" frame / window size after re-orientation in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686882/incorrect-frame-window-size-after-re-orientation-in-iphone)