# UIscrollView Positioning

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I'm having a few issues with UIscroll views. I've looked at the Reference entry for it but I cant seem to find out how to fix them. Basically I'm trying to insert a UIlabel into a Scroll view with the size 320 x 270 (Really the size is arbitrary at the moment). My problem is that I can't seem to get the UILabel to appear in the top left corner of the view.

```
    detailView.frame = frameDFull; // frameDFull = 320 x 500

    myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 150, 320, 270); //myFrame is the scroll view

    myView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    myView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 270);

    [self.view addSubview:myView];

    //UIView *viewHolder = [[UIView alloc]init];


    UILabel *eventDesc = [[UILabel alloc] init];


    eventDesc.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100);
    //eventDesc.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    eventDesc.text = @"Appears off the screen partially";

    [myView addSubview: eventDesc];


    [eventDesc release];
```

I can tell that I may have forgotten to do something here. but i'm not sure what. I tried to use a content align seeing as how its essentially a UIview but nothing happened.

Comment: Which one is the scroll view? What do you expect to happen? What is happening instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
UILabel *eventDesc = [[UILabel alloc] init];
```

with

```
UILabel *eventDesc = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
```

and deleting the line where you set the bounds. You should use the initWithFrame initializer for any UIView (and its subclasses), since the [frame determines the view's location within its superview, while the bounds determines the view's location within itself.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210047/iphone-development-whats-the-difference-between-the-frame-and-the-bounds)

Comment: Thank you very much I knew it was something small like that. I need to make sure I keep that in mind.