# Is there a way to literally pause the view?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, view

Can I pause a view for a certain amount of time? Basically, while an action is occurring, my view becomes messed up and I cannot figure out why. Everything gets shifted, and I've been looking through the code line by line for hours. So can I prevent the view from changing itself and then somehow resume it after the action is over? I really don't know if this is a stupid question, but thanks for your help!

Comment: Jack, you should instead find out why that is happening and fix it. That's the best advise I can give you. If you need help, I am here. :)

Comment: What is the action? What do you mean by "shifted"?

Comment: The action is sending something to a server, for whatever reason the entire view is shifted. After the view is shifted, I have the coordinates outputted to the log, and it thinks the view is at 0,0, even though it's not.

Comment: Check its superview frame, also check for any transformations.

Comment: Paste the code and let's solve the real problem instead

Comment: Believe me, I'd love to do that, but I'm not authorized to release the code. Ahhhhhhhh, I'll figure it out eventually and post my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The action is sending something to a server, for whatever reason the
>   entire view is shifted. After the view is shifted, I have the
>   coordinates outputted to the log, and it thinks the view is at 0,0,
>   even though it's not.

I think you might be getting mixed up in the distinction between frames & bounds?

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210047/iphone-development-whats-the-difference-between-the-frame-and-the-bounds) link

> The frame of an UIView is the rectangle, expressed as a location (x,y)
>   and size (width,height) relative to the superview it is contained
>   within.
>
> The bounds of an UIView is the rectangle, expressed as a location
>   (x,y) and size (width,height) relative to its own coordinate system
>   (0,0).

Essentially, if you're looking at the origin coordinates of the bounds of your view, it will always be 0,0. Instead, you should look at its frame coordinates. I hope this helps you in figuring out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no general mechanism for preventing changes to a view. If the view in question is your own UIView subclass, you can of course override the methods that modify the view and effectively prevent changes that way. That'd be a lot of work, however, and I don't think the result would be worth the effort; you'll be much better off finding the real problem and fixing it. It's always easier and better to work with the framework and not against it.