# self.bounds confusion

Tags: ios, core-graphics

In this code

> CGRect contextRect = self.bounds;

will refer which bound? rectangle, imageRect, or whole iOS view.

I am trying to manipulate image using quartz2D, i created this code by looking different examples, and code written between // is from Apple Quartz2D guide draw text.

Thanks in advance,
Regards.

```
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
        CGSize cgs = CGSizeMake(250.0, 400.0);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cgs);

        CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0,0,cgs.width,cgs.height);
        CGRect imageRect = CGRectInset(rectangle, 5.4, 5.4);
        imageRect.size.height -= 100;

        UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pumpkin.jpg"]; 
        [myImage drawInRect:imageRect];    

        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10.0);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        CGContextStrokeRect(context, rectangle);

        //    

        CGRect contextRect = self.bounds;

        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, contextRect.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);

        float w, h;
        w = contextRect.size.width;
        h = contextRect.size.height;

        CGAffineTransform myTextTransform;
        CGContextSelectFont (context, "Helvetica-Bold", h/10, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
        CGContextSetCharacterSpacing (context, 10);
        CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (context, kCGTextFillStroke);

        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 1, 0, .5);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 1, 1);
        myTextTransform =  CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
        CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, myTextTransform);
        CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 0, 50, "Quartz 2D", 9);

        //    

        UIImage *testImg =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        [testImg drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(35, 10)];
}
```

Comment: You could always refer to the iOS reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW1

Comment: Have you checked this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210047/iphone-development-whats-the-difference-between-the-frame-and-the-bounds

(Close as dupe?)

Comment: thanks for the reply, I already know the difference between frame and bound but I was confused regarding my code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`self.frame` indicates the coords and size of the view in its parent view coordinate system.

`self.bounds` indicates the coords and size of the view in its own coordinate system. So it always has the same `width` and `height` as `self.frame`, but it has `x` and `y` equal to `0`.

`self.bounds` is equal to `CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)`.

So your code:

```
CGRect contextRect = self.bounds;
```

is the same as:

```
CGRect contextRect = rect;
```