# UIScrollView changes bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm using a Navigation Controller for navigation.

My root view controller's UIView contains a UIScrollView which I added in the IB. I find that depending on my scrollView's current visible part, when I navigate from this view to another and return back, I find things very arbit.

Hope this description helps

When I dont scroll at all, there is no effect.

[image: Initial Image]

When I move forward and return back it remains the same.
However, when I scroll to the bottom of my scrollview as shown in the following figure

[image: Initial With Scroll]

Then navigating forward and then immediate backward lands me on this pic
[image: Final State]

Finally, I logged all the bounds, frame, content size of this scrollview to find the following weird change

```
2013-05-19 14:16:54.139 app2[1302:c07] {{0, 0}, {320, 392}}
2013-05-19 14:16:54.139 app2[1302:c07] {320, 456}
2013-05-19 14:16:54.140 app2[1302:c07] {{0, 0}, {320, 392}}
```

The above is the initial bounds, contentSize, frame respectively.
The below is after the navigation and back.

```
2013-05-19 14:20:47.490 app2[1302:c07] {{0, 64}, {320, 392}}
2013-05-19 14:20:47.490 app2[1302:c07] {320, 456}
2013-05-19 14:20:47.491 app2[1302:c07] {{0, 0}, {320, 392}}
```

I dont know what I did wrong. Please help me.

**Code**
This is the code, manipulating the scrollView

```
[self.scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:YES];
[self.scrollView setDelaysContentTouches:NO];
[self.scrollView setFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.scrollView setBounds:self.view.bounds];


- (IBAction)moreFiltersFunction:(UIButton*)sender {
sender.selected = !sender.isSelected;
if (sender.isSelected) {
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.moreFiltersView];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, self.scrollView.frame.size.height + 280)];
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:self.moreFiltersView.frame animated:YES];
} else {
    [self.moreFiltersView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, self.view.frame.size.height)];
}
```

}

Comment: The problem is your contentOffset. If you are changing the content offset somewhere, make sure that the method is not called before push.

Comment: @danypata: Please have a look at my updated post. i added the code where I'm manipulating the scrollView. Please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong. Also please explain me how contentOffset and bounds are related?

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you figure out how to fix it? I also see the bounds being changed when I navigate back to my scroll view, but I don't want to set the bounds manually since I'm doing everything using autolayout.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so first of all you don't need to set the bounds of the scroll view you just have to work with the frame.

A short description of the concept of bounds and frame from another SO post:(https://stackoverflow.com/a/1210141/2315974)

> The bounds of an UIView is the rectangle, expressed as a location
>   (x,y) and size (width,height) relative to its own coordinate system
>   (0,0).
>
> The frame of an UIView is the rectangle, expressed as a location (x,y)
>   and size (width,height) relative to the superview it is contained
>   within.

Another thing, I don't know when are you calling this `moreFiltersFunction` action but there is a little inconsistency between the values.

1. You should change the scrollView content size adding or subtraction values from the current   value of the scrollView contentSize. `[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, self.scrollView.contentSize.height + 280)];`
2. Be careful when using `scrollRectToVisible` method, if the rect sended as parameter is already visible, the scrollView won't scroll, also this method is changing the scroll view content offset.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I understand the relation between bounds and contentOffset. But still this doesn't resolve my problem. This time I logged my contentOffset and I found the relation between them.

Comment: If you found the answer, mark it as accepted so the question will not appear in the `unanswered` section.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't solve my problem. The way found out is to set the bounds, frame, contentSize and contentOffset to some default value in the viewWillAppear method, but I'm not satisfied with it.