# Translucent , setStatusBarStyle, UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiwebview, uiimageview

[image]I'm working on the UIWebView and what I want is for the webView not to over rap the view.

so here is the question. I set the UIWebView ,and the status bar is overlaid over the content.
How can I handle this? I coded as when I made the UIImage view, but at that time there is the navigation bar, and it worked well.

Also I did setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20).... but also doesn't work.  why the [ setFrame]; method doesn't work? Any ideas please.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
    [self.webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.amazon.com"];
    NSURLRequest *myURLReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
    [self.webView loadRequest:myURLReq];






}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

}


@end
```

**UPDATE:**  I switched off the Auto-layout and change  setFrame:CGRectMake(0, **20**) and now they are not overlaid. But I wonder why we need to set this? If I set the status bar translucent , it makes sense. But I set it as the default, which is supposed to start to draw the screen right below the status bar at (0,20).

Comment: I have tried your code but it has no issues - in my storyboard webview does not overlaps navigation bar as shown in your question - Turn your autolayout off - then try and these lines  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
    [self.webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)]; have no effect

Comment: @bgavya kothari: Thanks for the help, but I mean I didn't put the navigation bar. I'd love to know why it doesn't work without navigation bar, and how to fix this.

Comment: Then what you are using instead of navigation bar ???

Comment: I'm just testing the function out, so there's no points to add navigation bar here.(no scrolling the views.) just single mvc here. I didn't add anything.

Comment: Then what you have put on top 44px/64px

Comment: well nothing here, and I just wanted to know how to control the view because the latest version of iOS introduces lots of visual changes. I might not use this technically, but for the knowledge for the bug fixing or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this one**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];

  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleDefault];

    [self.webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

     NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.amazon.com"];

     NSURLRequest *myURLReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
     [self.webView loadRequest:myURLReq];
```

}

**Your autosize masks should look like this.**

[image: Your autosize masks should look like this]

**Final Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add following code in your viewDidLoadMethod :

```
 if( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
    {
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    }
```