# Changing bounds of a child view centers it in its parent

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, layout, uiview

I have been following a tutorial explaining a custom ios control. There is no problem with the tutorial but I got really confused about the frame/bounds clipping (not part of the tutorial).

I have a UIView instance in the scene in the storyboard. This UIView is sized at 120 x 120. I am adding a custom control (extending UIControl) to this container view with `addSubview`. I began to experiment with setting different widths and height to the frame and bounds of the custom control, this is the initializer of the control:

```
 public override init(frame: CGRect) {
     super.init(frame: frame)
     createSublayers()
 }
```

...and produces this result (red is the parent, blue circle is the child):

[image: full circle]

Now I change the init to this:

```
public override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    createSublayers()
    self.frame.size.width = 40
    self.frame.size.height = 40
    println("frame: \(self.frame)")
    println("bounds: \(self.bounds)")
    self.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

And that produces this result:

[image: frame]
and prints:
frame: (0.0,0.0,40.0,40.0)
bounds: (0.0,0.0,40.0,40.0)

But when I change the initliazer to this:

```
public override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    createSublayers()
    self.bounds.size.width = 40
    self.bounds.size.height = 40
    println("frame: \(self.frame)")
    println("bounds: \(self.bounds)")
    self.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

I get this:

[image: bounds]
and prints: frame: (40.0,40.0,40.0,40.0)
bounds: (0.0,0.0,40.0,40.0)

I cannot seem to comprehend why this view is centered in its parent view when I change its bounds. What exactly is causing it? Is the 'frame' clipped always towards its center? Or is this view centered in its parent after the bounds have been modified and that causes the update of the 'frame'? Is it some property that can be changed? How could I manage to put it to top-left corner, for example (exactly in the same way as when I modify the 'frame')? Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var knobPlaceholder: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var valueLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var valueSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet var animateSwitch: UISwitch!
    var knob: Knob!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        knob = Knob(frame: knobPlaceholder.bounds)
        knobPlaceholder.addSubview(knob)
        knobPlaceholder.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();
    }

    @IBAction func sliderValueChanged(slider: UISlider) {
    }

    @IBAction func randomButtonTouched(button: UIButton) {
    }
}
```

And the knob:

```
public class Knob: UIControl {

    private let knobRenderer = KnobRenderer()
    private var backingValue: Float = 0.0

    /** Contains the receiver’s current value. */
    public var value: Float {
        get {
            return backingValue
        }
        set {
            setValue(newValue, animated: false)
        }
    }

    /** Sets the receiver’s current value, allowing you to animate the change visually. */
    public func setValue(value: Float, animated: Bool) {
        if value != backingValue {
            backingValue = min(maximumValue, max(minimumValue, value))
        }
    }

    /** Contains the minimum value of the receiver. */
    public var minimumValue: Float = 0.0

    /** Contains the maximum value of the receiver. */
    public var maximumValue: Float = 1.0

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        createSublayers()
        self.bounds.size.width = 40
        self.bounds.size.height = 40
        println("frame: \(self.frame)")
        println("bounds: \(self.bounds)")
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    public required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func createSublayers() {
        knobRenderer.update(bounds)
        knobRenderer.strokeColor = tintColor
        knobRenderer.startAngle = -CGFloat(M_PI * 11.0 / 8.0);
        knobRenderer.endAngle = CGFloat(M_PI * 3.0 / 8.0);
        knobRenderer.pointerAngle = knobRenderer.startAngle;
        knobRenderer.lineWidth = 2.0
        knobRenderer.pointerLength = 6.0

        layer.addSublayer(knobRenderer.trackLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(knobRenderer.pointerLayer)
    }

}

private class KnobRenderer {
    let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let pointerLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    var strokeColor: UIColor {
        get {
            return UIColor(CGColor: trackLayer.strokeColor)
        }

        set(strokeColor) {
            trackLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.CGColor
            pointerLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.CGColor
        }
    }

    var lineWidth: CGFloat = 1.0 {
        didSet {
            update();
        }
    }

    var startAngle: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            update();
        }
    }

    var endAngle: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            update()
        }
    }

    var backingPointerAngle: CGFloat = 0.0

    var pointerAngle: CGFloat {
        get { return backingPointerAngle }
        set { setPointerAngle(newValue, animated: false) }
    }

    func setPointerAngle(pointerAngle: CGFloat, animated: Bool) {
        backingPointerAngle = pointerAngle
    }

    var pointerLength: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            update()
        }
    }

    init() {
        trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        pointerLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    }

    func updateTrackLayerPath() {
        let arcCenter = CGPoint(x: trackLayer.bounds.width / 2.0, y: trackLayer.bounds.height / 2.0)
        let offset = max(pointerLength, trackLayer.lineWidth / 2.0)
        let radius = min(trackLayer.bounds.height, trackLayer.bounds.width) / 2.0 - offset;
        trackLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true).CGPath
    }

    func updatePointerLayerPath() {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: pointerLayer.bounds.width - pointerLength - pointerLayer.lineWidth / 2.0, y: pointerLayer.bounds.height / 2.0))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: pointerLayer.bounds.width, y: pointerLayer.bounds.height / 2.0))
        pointerLayer.path = path.CGPath
    }

    func update(bounds: CGRect) {
        let position = CGPoint(x: bounds.width / 2.0, y: bounds.height / 2.0)

        trackLayer.bounds = bounds
        trackLayer.position = position

        pointerLayer.bounds = bounds
        pointerLayer.position = position

        update()
    }

    func update() {
        trackLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        pointerLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth

        updateTrackLayerPath()
        updatePointerLayerPath()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code from the parent view that is showing the child?

Comment: Also, please add your drawing function for the circle.

Comment: @miken.mkndev Added both. Thanks for reading.

Comment: In the first, you have assigned the `frame`; in the second you have assigned the `bounds`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210047/cocoa-whats-the-difference-between-the-frame-and-the-bounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your update function you are centering the view.

```
func update(bounds: CGRect) {
        **let position = CGPoint(x: bounds.width / 2.0, y: bounds.height / 2.0)**

        trackLayer.bounds = bounds
        trackLayer.position = position

        pointerLayer.bounds = bounds
        pointerLayer.position = position

        update()
    }
```

If you take that out, then you're view won't be centered anymore. The reason setting the frame would leave it in the upper left hand corner while setting the bounds resulted in it being in the center is because setting the bounds x/y does not override the frame x/y. When you set the frame then later on your code only sets the bounds, so the frame x/y is never overwritten so the view stays in the upper left hand corner. However, in the second there is no x/y set for the frame, so I guess it's taken what you set for the bounds, so it get's centered.

I would recommend not setting the bounds x/y for the view as that should always be 0, 0. If you want to reposition it then use the frame. Remember the frame is relative the parent while the bounds is relative to it's self.

Comment: Gosh, how could I have missed that. Thanks a lot!