# Gradient not covering full frame SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimageview

I have the following extension to `imageView`:

```
extension UIImageView {
func addBlackGradientLayer(frame: CGRect){
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = frame
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
    gradient.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    self.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
}}

imageView.addBlackGradientLayer(frame: imageView.frame)
```

on applying this to the imageView, I am having the following output. I tried setting the constraints and also, the autolayout.

Following is the output after the execution:

[image]

Comment: It makes sense to leave a reason for downvote, otherwise its a stupid move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call

```
imageView.addBlackGradientLayer(frame: imageView.bounds)
```

See: [Cocoa: What's the difference between the frame and the bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210047/cocoa-whats-the-difference-between-the-frame-and-the-bounds)

Comment: Hey i already tried it. Well, if I run this on a iphone simulator 7+, It shows this issue. While the gradient is properly visible when I run it on my 6s and 7+ devices. Can it be a simulator issue?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your error on a 7+ simulator.

Comment: Maybe your view gets resized after the gradient layer is applied. I suggest checking the frame when the layer is added and after the view did show.

Comment: Yeah its printing the same frame size. The issue is the frame only. I wonder why is it behaving this way, Even though appropriate constraints are set

Comment: I am using a collection header view and have a image view that completely wraps the bounds of the header. On printing the frame and bound values, It return the same value. I really dont know what am I doing wrong

Comment: I suggest to debug the view hierarchy after the view has been displayed. Check the views frame when it's visible via the debugger and print it's layer's sublayer property.

Comment: you are right! My view is somehow screwing up. I'll keep you posted.