# Having trouble finding y positions of elements inside scrollview using frame.origin.y

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 elements inside a scrollview.

Element 1 gives out 390.0 after finding its y position using frame.origin.y

As for Element 2, I've attempted to place it in the exact same position as Element 1 (y = 390.0) by writing below :

```
Element2.frame.origin.y = yPosition
```

Unfortunately, Element 2 moves upwards only slightly (its was originally far below Element 1) ... it doesn't move to the position given by Element 1 yet the frame.origin.y of both elements are now the same. What could be the problem?

Comment: It's likely that the two elements have a different parent view. Frames are relative.

Comment: @the4kman thanks, they're both inside the scrollview. I honestly don't know how they could both have different parent views. Are bounds relative too?

Comment: Bounds are relative to a view's own coordinate system. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1210141/3151675

Comment: Even if they are both inside the scrollview, they can be nested in different UIViews, in that case the frame would be relative to their parent UIView, which may not be the same. If that's the case you can use `element1.convert(element1.frame.origin, to: scrollView)` this will give you the element 1 origin relative to the scrollView

Comment: Pl Add some code

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the frame of the element 1 is not converted to self.view , so it;s relative to the scrollView , not to self.view , You can try

```
 let ret = self.elem1.convert(self.elem1.frame, to: self.view)

 print(ret.origin.y)
```

Comment: And how do I get the y-position value? I've tried "ret.frame.origin.y" and it says "Value of type 'CGRect' has no member 'frame"

Comment: use rec.origin.y

Comment: Element1.frame.origin.y = (Element2.convert(Element2.frame, to: self.view).origin.y) Tried the above and Element2 is sent way up above Element1. They're both inside the scrollview. I only want them to be in the exact same position.

Answer (score 1):

First, convert the scroll view's coordinate to the main view's coordinate perspective. Then, access the the `y` value through the `origin`

```
let ret = self.elem1.convert(self.elem1.frame, to: self.view).origin.y
```

Comment: Element1.frame.origin.y = (Element2.convert(Element2.frame, to: self.view).origin.y)

Tried the above and Element2 is sent way up above Element1. They're both inside the scrollview. I only want them to be in the exact same position.