# Swift: How to get Height and width of a rotated image.

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image, uiimageview

I am rotating a square image View whose width is 160 but after rotation width become 190 same as height.

Rotating it by this function

```
func transformUsingRecognizer(_ recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, transform: CGAffineTransform) -> CGAffineTransform {

        if let rotateRecognizer = recognizer as? UIRotationGestureRecognizer {
            return transform.rotated(by: rotateRecognizer.rotation)
        }
       return transform
}
```

tried these two codes to get correct width

```
imgDraggingImage.bounds.size.width
imgDraggingImage.frame.height
```

but no success.

Image before rotation width 160

[image]

Image after rotation, no change in width but now returning width 190

[image]

Seems width value depends on rotation as on any different angle it returns different width value. But I need correct value which in this case is 160. please help

Comment: Have you tried this? CGSize newImageSize = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(oldImageSize, currentTransform);

Comment: Possibly Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28917673/5501940

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
extension CGAffineTransform {
    var angle: CGFloat { return atan2(-self.c, self.a) }

    var angleInDegrees: CGFloat { return self.angle * 180 / .pi }

    var scaleX: CGFloat {
        let angle = self.angle
        return self.a * cos(angle) - self.c * sin(angle)
    }

    var scaleY: CGFloat {
        let angle = self.angle
        return self.d * cos(angle) + self.b * sin(angle)
    }
}
```

The above extension solve the problem.

```
  self.imgDraggingImage.transform.scaleX
  self.imgDraggingImage.transform.scaleY
```

the above code **scaleX** gave change in Width of image (scale) even if rotated too and **scaleY** provide the % change in image height.

where **imgDraggingImage.bounds.size.width** gave constant image size even if image scaled.

while **imgDraggingImage.frame.width** was creating issue when image was rotated.

Comment: This works great, could you give an explanation of the maths behind it? I've forgotten my school maths!

Answer (score 0):

Depends, do you want the size in Pixels or in Points:

```
let heightInPoints = image.size.height
let heightInPixels = heightInPoints * image.scale

let widthInPoints = image.size.width
let widthInPixels = widthInPoints * image.scale
```