# Adding a gradient to UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I'm trying to add a gradient to UIImageView.

```
viewDidLoad() {
    self.bookImageBig.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.book.image), placeholderImage: nil)
    self.bookImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.book.image), placeholderImage: nil)
    
    let view = UIView(frame: bookImageBig.frame)

    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = view.frame
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
    gradient.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    bookImageBig.addSubview(view)
    bookImageBig.bringSubviewToFront(view)
```

I'm trying to add a gradient to bookImageBig UIImageView.

However, the gradient only partially covers the image. 30px of the image is not covered by the gradient. The image was added to the story board and is being referenced in the view controller.
Can someone please help?

Comment: Not only do you confuse frame with bounds, but you have concealed _when_ this code runs, which is crucial. If you run it in `viewDidLoad`, that’s bad.

Comment: @matt I run it in viewDidLoad. Where should I run it?

Comment: After the first `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Until then, the sizes are not right. Please read http://www.programmingios.net/premature-layout/

Comment: @matt I'm still confused. Where would you call it if it has to be called after viewDidLayoutSubviews and viewDidLayoutSubviews is called many times?

Comment: You do it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and you use a Bool instance property so you know this is the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of frame use bounds

```
gradient.frame = self.bookImageBig.bounds
```

For frame and bounds difference look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210047/cocoa-whats-the-difference-between-the-frame-and-the-bounds)

Comment: That did not work. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: can you share demo project ?

Comment: Here's the code https://gist.github.com/naissa12/951021a05a7a2d9edcda52dbd8e139d6