# Difference between view's frame and view's bound + iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiview

I want to know what is the difference between 'frame' and 'bound' property of UIView. I get the same results using both properties. I can not figure out the difference between the two..

Thanx in advance.

Comment: This is a duplicate to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071112/uiviews-frame-bounds-center-origin-when-to-use-what

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The frame is the view's location in its superview, using the superview's coordinate system.

The bounds is the view's location and size in its own coordinate system.

If you are getting the same results for both properties, it means that the view fills its superview, and both views have (0, 0) as the origin.  Try changing the frame, and you will see it move to different positions within its superview.

Answer (score 5):

This is [covered in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html). The frame and bounds are two different coordinate systems.

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late but as this a common question so I am posting a [link to apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW5) to have a detailed explanation on this