# iPhone Development - What's the Difference between the Origin and the bounds?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

iPhone Development - What's the Difference between the Origin and the bounds?

Comment: great resource here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIView's frame, bounds, center, origin, when to use what?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071112/uiviews-frame-bounds-center-origin-when-to-use-what)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The origin is where view starts so 0,0 for example would mean that the view is in the top left corner of the screen.

The bounds is the size and orgin of the screen together. So if the size is 10, 10 and the origin is 0, 0 then a view is located in the top left of the screen and is 10 pixels x 10 pixels.

Edit 1: More detail

Bounds is a CGRect ([Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGRect))

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the `bounds` and the `frame` of a view are very similar things, but not the same. The `frame` describes the `origin` (location/position) and `size` of the view in it's parent view's coordinate system. The `bounds` describes them in the view's coordinate system. That's why usually the `origin` of the `bounds` is (0, 0) and the size's are the same.

So to answer your question, the `origin` (a `CGPoint`) and the `size` (a `CGSize`) of a view in it's own coordinate system make up it's `bounds` (a `CGRect`).