# bounds vs frame of a UIAlertView

Tags: objective-c, uikit

I have UIAlertView and I log it's frame and bounds using:

```
  [self.alertView show];
  NSLog(@"frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.alertView.frame));
  NSLog(@"bounds: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.alertView.bounds));
```

I notice that the width and height of the frame and bounds is different. How is this possible?

Comment: It's totally plausible. Out of curiosity, which values do you get?

Comment: frame: {{3.8, 118}, {312.4, 264}}  bounds: {{0, 0}, {284, 240}}

Comment: It is not recommended to check the values of these properties on `UIAlertView`. There is no documentation that these values are to remain consistent across releases of iOS. Note that `UIAlertView` is deprecated in iOS 8 in favor of `UIAlertController`. This is the way alerts should be presented moving forward…

Answer (score 2):

From [UIView's frame, bounds, center, origin, when to use what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071112/uiviews-frame-bounds-center-origin-when-to-use-what)

> **frame** - this is the property you most often use for normal iPhone applications. most controls will be laid out relative to the "containing" control so the `frame.origin` will directly correspond to where the control needs to display, and `frame.size` will determine how big to make the control.
>
> **bounds** - this property is not a positioning property, but defines the drawable area of the `UIView` "relative" to the frame. By default this property is usually *(0, 0, width, height)*.

That being said, it's not surprising nor uncommon for the `bounds` size to be different from the `frame` size. Since in this case the `bounds` rect is smaller than the `frame` it simply means that only a part of the `view` is being drawn.

Also consider that `UIAlertView` view hierarchy it's much more complex than it appears and it also went through a big change with iOS 7.

To further remark this, here's a statement from the documentation

> The `UIAlertView` class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

Which is a nice way to say: *here be dragons!*