# Playing video chosen in ViewController in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl, mpmovieplayer

I have a Master-Detail Application. In there, I've been able to download a XML file and use it as an array.

But I want to choose a tab and have it to play a video.

All of this works except in the following code block.

> - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

When I try to alloc a MPMoviePlayer, it crashes the program.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

**Code :**

**MasterViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *presidents;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *number;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *years;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *party;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *image;

@end
```

**MasterViewController.m**

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController () {
NSMutableArray *_objects;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

@synthesize number, name, years, party, image;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
[super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.navigationItem.title=@"Presidents";

NSString *urlStr = [[NSString alloc]
                    initWithFormat:@"http://pickupboyd.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Presidents12.plist"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
_presidents = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];


name = [_presidents objectForKey:@"Names"];
years = [_presidents objectForKey:@"Years"];
party = [_presidents objectForKey:@"Party"];
image = [_presidents objectForKey:@"Images"];



[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
if (!_objects) {
    _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
[_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
 }

 #pragma mark - Table View

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//This is to the get count of the array in dictionary "Presidents" called Number
number = [_presidents objectForKey:@"Number"];
return number.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


NSString *nameOfPresident = [name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = nameOfPresident;

NSString *datesInOffice = [years objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = datesInOffice;

//set the image view-------------------------------------


NSString *presidentImages = [image objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:presidentImages];


return cell;
}

 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    [_objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
} else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
}
 }



 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    NSURL *movieURL = [party objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    [[player view] setFrame:[self.view bounds]];
    [self.view addSubview:[player view]];
    [player play];

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *playVideo = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:movieURL];

    //NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    [[segue destinationViewController] presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playVideo];
}
 }

 @end
```

**DetailViewController.h**

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

 @interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

 @property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;

 @end
```

DetailViewController.m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController

#pragma mark - Managing the detail item


 - (void)configureView
{
// Update the user interface for the detail item.

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
[self configureView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you provide any information about the crash?

Comment: Please try adding only relevant parts of your code rather than just pasting the whole file. Also always include the error that you get.

Comment: Sorry and thank you for the input. My apologies for the delay.  The error is:  in Main - Thread 1:  signal SIGABRT.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
[[player view] setFrame:[self.view bounds]];
```

To this:

```
[[player view] setFrame:[self.view frame]];
```

And see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071112/uiviews-frame-bounds-center-origin-when-to-use-what) for the differences between bounds and frame.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I did try this, but still received the main error.  I will continue to work at this.  This is my first time posting, so I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code i use for playing video in a view after a button tap

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

{
NSURL * videoURL;
UITableView * view;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController*player;


-(IBAction)playMovie;

@end

.m

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)playMovie
{
NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                 pathForResource:@"testy3 (Converted)" ofType:@"mov"];
self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
               initWithContentURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];

// Play Partial Screen
self.player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400);
[self.view addSubview:self.player.view];

// Play Movie
[self.player play];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: I will try this today and let you know.  It looks that perhaps I have not allocated a MPMoviePlayer?? Thanks again!

Comment: So, just to be clear, would it be better to allocate a UIView than to try to use the segue method to do this in the Detail ViewController?  It looks as if you basically allocate the UIView when needed and don't really use the storyboard segue?  Thank you, just trying to get my head around all of this.