# How to make a subview fill its superview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, subview, addsubview, superview

I can't find the answer here anyway, nor do I see a duplicate question.

My code is simple. Given 3 UIView, parent, from and to, remove from from parent and add subview. + add animation but that's just doodads.

Now, the problem is when I do that, the to then get offsetted. It's as if it's pushed down.

I even add        To.frame=ParentView.frame; to make sure it works. It doesn't.

What should I have done?

```
+ (void) AnimateSwitchingWithParent: (UIView *) ParentView From: (UIView *) From To: (UIView* ) To
{
    /*[UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.25];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];


    [UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:ParentView cache:YES];*/
    [From removeFromSuperview];
    [ParentView addSubview:To];

    To.frame=ParentView.frame; //If I don't do this, the subview is still off by around 20 points
    NSLog(@"To.bounds: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(To.bounds));
    NSLog(@"From.bounds.: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(From.bounds));
    NSLog(@"ParentView.bounds: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(ParentView.bounds));


    //JA_DUMP (To.bounds);
    //JA_DUMP (To.bounds);



    /*[UIView commitAnimations];*/

}
```

I have figured out the solution. Turns out the frame of To is

To.frames: {{0, 0}, {320, 372}}

However, if I remove To.frame=ParentView.frame the frame is also

{{0, 20}, {320, 460}}

I wonder why? 20 points seem to be the distance of the status bar. Where can we set that frame in InterfaceBuilder?

I set statusbar to none in SimulatedMetric section.

Comment: Objective-C conventions expect variables to start with a lowercase letter (uppercase is for class/protocol names only). Please stick to them. Your (future?) co-workers will thank you for it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Seems you misunderstand the frame and bounds, revise your code to `To.frame=ParentView.bounds;` should be OK.

Related: [Why is there an frame rectangle and an bounds rectangle in an UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749558/why-is-there-an-frame-rectangle-and-an-bounds-rectangle-in-an-uiview)

Comment: The point is that the `frame` is in the coordinates of the superview's superview. `bounds` is in the coordinates of the view. If you use `frame` and the superview is offset within it's parent, this won't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Fix "`20 points`" difference from bottom in subView and View in Swift:

```
To.frame = NSRect(origin: CGPoint(x: ParentView.bounds.origin.x, 
                                  y: ParentView.bounds.origin.y-20), 
                    size: ParentView.bounds.size)
```