# .xib in UIView doesn't fill full width

Tags: objective-c, uiview, xib

I have a screen in which i have an UIView : the footer container.
In this UIView i add a subview : my footer with some labels, buttons... which are in another .xib.

My footer container (the UIView) adapts its width perfectly according with the screen size on different devices, as expected.

However, the content (aka the .xib elements : labels, buttons...) doesn't fit the whole container width (fills only 1/3)

Here you can see the result (in pink this is the UIView, the container) :
http://fr.tinypic.com/r/anoors/8

I'm a newbie with constraints, everything is in "wC hR" for size class, which works perfectly for the container...
Any idea how i can tell the .xib to fill whole the container?

Thx

Comment: If you are using auto layout, which it seems that you are, pin the content the left (leading space), right (trailing space), top and bottom of the Superview

Comment: That's done already :/

Comment: Ok i found the solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402271/how-to-make-a-subview-fill-its-superview