# Adding padding to an UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit

I'm looking for a way to add a `padding` property to an UIView. Ideally, I would like to avoid subclassing and putting it in a category. The usage would be something like:

```
myview.padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
```

And maybe have a `paddingBox` property as well which would return a `CGRect` describing the size and position of the inner padding box.

Now, how would one implement in a category something like that. I initially though of using `bounds`, but unfortunately the size of the `bounds` is linked to the size of the `frame` (always the same) only the coordinates can differ.

Comment: If you are thinking of `padding` in the Android sense – a space in which the view background is drawn but not its content – I think iOS just does not have that concept built in to its views. Strange, right?

Answer (score 57):

This is generally done by setting the bounds within the view. So if you wanted an inset of 10 all round you could do:

```
view.bounds = CGRectInset(view.frame, 10.0f, 10.0f);
```

The bounds defines the drawable area of the view, relative to the frame. So this should give in effect a padding. You can then get the 'paddingBox' just from the bounds.

Hope this helps! :)

Update in Swift 5+, It's

```
view.bounds = view.frame.insetBy(dx: 10.0, dy: 10.0);
```

Comment: This changes the size of the view as well, unfortunately. As I mentioned in my question, the docs state that `The size of the bounds rectangle is coupled to the size of the frame rectangle, so that changes to one affect the other.`. In other terms, the code you posted should have a -10 not 10 and even so, it will add only top and left padding, but I'll test again, just to be sure I'm not missing something.

Comment: Do you have a link to the docs, as I'm pretty sure that the size of the bounds and frame can differ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749558/why-is-there-an-frame-rectangle-and-an-bounds-rectangle-in-an-uiview and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071112/uiviews-frame-bounds-center-origin-when-to-use-what are good info on this.

Comment: Hmmm, just found it in the docs, am just doing an experiment to confirm. I would now like to apologise, as that is in fact the case. Looks like you may have to go for a simple subclass.

Comment: ```self.contentTextView.bounds =  self.contentTextView.frame.insetBy(dx: 10, dy: 10)``` (***Swift 5+*** )

Comment: This is totally wrong

Answer (score 41):

**Update for Swift 3**

```
view.bounds = view.frame.insetBy(dx: 10.0, dy: 10.0)
```

:)

Answer (score 41):

**Update**: Since iOS11 you should use `directionalLayoutMargins` instead of `layoutMargins`.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622566-layoutmargins?language=objc

Since iOS 8, each view has now a `layoutMargins` property which corresponds to the padding.

```
myview.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
```

When you use AutoLayout, a format with `|-[subview]-|`, `|-` will refer to the edges defined with `layoutMargins`.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622566-layoutmargins?language=objc

Answer (score 15):

You can override the alignmentRectInsets property. Here is an example in Swift 4

```
class YourCustomView: UIView {

    override var alignmentRectInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

What you really have to do is create a view and add a subview to it. Make one view the background and give it the frame you want. Then make the second subview the frame you want with the edge insets.

```
UIView backgroundView = new UIView(CGRect.FromLTRB(0, 0, 100, 100))
{
    BackgroundColor = backgroundGray,
};

//Will have a right edge inset of 10
UIView edgyView = new UIView(CGRect.FromLTRB(0, 0, 90, 100))
{
    BackgroundColor = backgroundGray,
}

backgroundView.AddSubview(edgyView);
```

Answer (score 7):

Update for Swift 4:

```
self.yourView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inset the view's frame/bounds like this:

```
    yourView.frame = yourView.frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: .zero, left: 5.0, bottom: 5.0, right: .zero)
```