# UIViewController's view.center not always the same value

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

My animations in a view controller depend on there being a fixed value of `self.view.center`. However, depending on my navigation flow, my self.view.center has a different value (41.5f difference on iPhone X, iOS 11).

Can someone explain why that would be? Has it something to do with extended layouts? Changing the status bar/tab bar/nav bar?

Can I get the exact value through another method?

I have already tried:

```
CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds); //-> same problem applies here
```

Answer (score 1):

`UIView`'s `center` property is the center of the view's `frame`. The `frame`'s coordinate system [is that of the *super*view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/749876). So, indeed, the value of `center` depends on the context where the view finds itself.

For the center of the view in its *own* coordinate system, you need to look at the its `bounds` rectangle. The `CGRectGetMidX()` and `CGRectGetMidY()` will give you the values you need for the center point.

Comment: You mean CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds);? I have already tried that, but there is still a different value (by 41.5 points).

Comment: Is the view's size different? Is there a transform applied?

Comment: No, not at all. It is the same view in a ViewController, all it depends on is the navigation path before it gets called (with one particular ViewController that seems to cause the view.center-change, but I have no idea what changes in that ViewController).

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing center or bounds in the viewDidLoad () method. Try it in the viewDidAppear() it will give you the correct center position of the view controller's view

Comment: I have tried to get the values in both the viewDidAppear() and viewDidLoad() methods. Also tried: viewWillAppear() viewDidLayoutSubviews() -> same problem there.